# Parsing Error on WebServer (live Server) and no Parsing Error on Local Machine

Tags: php, yii

I developed and tested an application on my local machine.. everything works perfectly!
When I migrated this to a live server I keep getting all the parsing errors!! 
For e.g

I don't know what is the error on the following code?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/content/index.php on line 126
```

Line 126 is line 3 (starting from items) below

```
<?php 

     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbCarousel', 
      array(
        'items'=>array_map(function($record){
          return array(

            'image' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/'.CHtml::encode($record['file_location']),
            'label'=>$this->renderPartial("_frontlabel",array('record'=>$record),true),
            'imageOptions'=>array('style'=>'height: auto; max-height: 1000px; overflow:auto; max-width: 900px;margin-bottom: 0 auto;'),

            'itemOptions' => array('class'=>'carousel-inner','style'=>'height:800px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px'),
            'captionOptions'=>array('style'=>'background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);'),
            'caption'=>$this->renderPartial("_frontCaptionContent",array('record'=>$record,'cc'=>new ECurrencyHelper()),true),

            );
        },$dataProvider->getdata()),


        ));
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of you are using **[anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)** in below line:

```
'items'=>array_map(function($record){
      return array(
      ...
```

This feature is available as of `PHP` version `5.3` and above. So you need to upgrade your server's `PHP` version to +`5.3` or you should not use anonymous functions.

Comment: Thanks I noticed that